# How to get weights from keras advanced layers?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

When using "normal" keras layers from tensorflow.keras.layers.activation one can obtain the layer weights using layer.get_weights(). This normally returns a list of numpy arrays. In case of LeakyRelu, this list is empty though.

https://keras.io/layers/about-keras-layers/

expected: weights of the layer as a list of Numpy arrays
actual: empty list

Comment: Most non-linear activations do not have trainable weights. Are you trying to get the weights of a `Dense` layer?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the weights of any layer with `layer.get_weights()`, but not all layers have weights. The problem here is conceptual, the Leaky ReLU activation does not have any trainable weights, so it is correct that the list returned by `get_weights()` is empty.

Maybe you are thinking of the PReLU activation, which does have trainable weights.